# Inserting 3 strings before each date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

My current code is getting 3 dates from the user and displaying them to the user like

```
2013-2-23
2013-2-22
2013-1-19
```

However I want it to do more than the `\n`. I would love it to do be able to place 3 words like

```
start 2013-2-23
middle 2013-2-22
end  2014-2-24
```

How would I have to change this code?

```
$( "#selectdate" ).datepicker({
  //altField: "#comment",
  numberOfMonths:1,
  dateFormat: "yy mm dd",
  altFormat: "dd mm yy", 
  minDate: -0,
  onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $("#selectdate").val('');
    if($('#comment').val()!='') {
      $('#comment').val($('#comment').val()+'\n'+selectedDate);
    } else {
      $('#comment').val(selectedDate);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a few questions jump out after first reading this: Are you always going to use the same DatePicker to select the three dates? Are there always going to be three? and Are the dates ever entered out of order?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those labels in an array and access the label using an incrementing index.

```
var counter = 0; //incrementing index

var label = ['start', 'middle', 'end']; //labels

$( "#selectdate" ).datepicker({
  //altField: "#comment",
  numberOfMonths:1,
  dateFormat: "yy mm dd",
  altFormat: "dd mm yy", 
  minDate: -0,
  onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    if(counter==3) counter = 0; //to avoid accessing non-existent array index go back to 0
    $("#selectdate").val('');
    if($('#comment').val()!='') {
      $('#comment').val($('#comment').val()+'\n'+ label[counter] + ' ' + selectedDate);
    } else {
      $('#comment').val(label[counter] + ' ' + selectedDate);
    }
    counter++; //increment the label index
  }
});
```

Comment: It's up to you to stop appending the dates when the counter reaches 3.